# Como criar e modificar o mesmo registro com Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de agendamento porém me deparei com a seguinte dificuldade:

Na tabela de agendamento (`Appointment`) possui um campo `quantidade` e gostaria que cada vez que fosse criado um registro adicionasse +1 nesse campo, e quando esse campo chegasse ao valor `6` retornasse o erro `'Agendamento já preenchido'`.

Porém, a função `create` do Sequelize cria um novo registro com um novo `id`. Gostaria de editar o registro já criado, tentei com condicional (se registro existir , faça isso...), porém não deu certo.

Alguma ideia de como fazer isso? Segue código abaixo:

```
import { startOfHour, parseISO, isBefore } from 'date-fns';
import Appointment from '../models/Appointment';

class AppointmentController {
    async store(req, res) {
        const { date } = req.body;

        const hourStart = startOfHour(parseISO(date));

        // Checando horas vencidas
        if (isBefore(hourStart, new Date())) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Data vencida' });
        }

        // Checando disponibilidade do agendamento
        const checkAvailability = await Appointment.findOne({
            where: {
                date: hourStart,
                canceled_at: null,
                quantidade: 6,
            },
        });

        if (checkAvailability) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Agendamento já preenchido' });
        }

        // Criando agendamento
        const appointment = await Appointment.create({
            user_id: req.userId,
            date,
            qualidade: +1,
        });

        return res.json(appointment);
    }
}

export default new AppointmentController();
```

Comment: Você diz que quer que adicione +1 ao invés de criar um novo registro. Isso significa que sempre terá o `date` valendo `hourStart`e o `canceled_at` como `null`? Estou em dúvida se você está tendo um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/100416) aí

Comment: Caso o agendamento seja no mesmo horário quero que adicione ao campo quantidade +1 se o horário for diferente ai será um novo registro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos esclarecer algumas coisas primeiro:

- O equivalente ao `INSERT` no Sequelize é `Modelo.create({ dados })`.
- O `UPDATE` possui duas opções "equivalentes" no Sequelize:

```
Modelo.update({ nome: "Novo Nome" }, {
  where: { "identificador": "X" }
});
```

ou

```
const instancia = await Modelo.create({ nome: "João" });
console.log(instancia.nome); // "João"
instancia.nome = "Rafael";
// O nome ainda é "João" no banco de dados
await instancia.save();
// Agora o nome foi atualizado para "Rafael" no banco de dados
```

---

Adaptando isso para o seu caso, pode-se usar um `find` para encontrar um agendamento no horário especificado e então fazer as verificações necessárias:

```
//...

// Busca o agendamento no horário especificado
const appointment = await Appointment.findOne({
  where: {
    date: hourStart,
    canceled_at: null
  }
});

if (appointment == null) {
  // Não existe, então cria o agendamento
  const appointment = await Appointment.create({
    user_id: req.userId,
    date,
    qualidade: 1
  });
} else if (appointment.quantidade < 6) {
  // Já existe e é válido, então atualiza a quantidade no banco
  appointment.quantidade += 1;
  await appointment.save();
} else {
  // Possui quantidade >= 6, então retorna o erro
  return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Agendamento já preenchido' });
}

// Retorna o agendamento
return res.json(appointment);

//...
```

Comment: Obrigado Rafael, a sua solução para minha pergunta está correta, após aplicar identifquei que desta forma não seria ideal para minha aplicação pois gravaria tudo em apenas 1 registro no bd, solucionei de outra forma o meu novo problema mas para a questão o seu código funcionou, agradeço.